# Unable to spawn "ffmpeg" after building an electron app on Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, child-process, spawn

I developed an Electron App on Mac OS X and I'm able to do childProcess.spawn("ffmpeg");

ffmpeg is on my path. Everything works.

But once I build the Electron app, spawning "ffmpeg" gives me "ENOENT" error.

What goes wrong or what is different when we build an Electron App?